# Python gives error if I run this code from cmd, however runs fine if I run it from Jupyter

Tags: python, input, while-loop, try-except

## My code:

Basically, I am reading in inputs in a list. It should give an error if its not an integer, and skip that input and stop when i write "done". Then I am creating a count, sum and average, which I print.

```
total = 0
count = 0
list = []

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        fnum = float(num)
        list.append(fnum)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        print(fnum, type(fnum))
        continue
print(list)
for i in list:
    count += 1
    total += i
print(total, count, "Average: ", total/count)
```

## Error message

Like I said, it runs fine from Jupyter or Colab, but I get the following error message from cmd:

### If I enter a random string:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:location\file.py", line 6, in <module>
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'asd' is not defined
```

### If I enter done:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:location\file.py", line 6, in <module>
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'done' is not defined
```

Comment: Are you running this in python 2?

Comment: Using a bare `except` like that is bad practice, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except. Naming a variable `list` is also a terrible idea, be careful!

Comment: thank you! yes, unfortunately i was running this in python 2. but when i typed python3 in cmd, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're running it using Python 2. Jupyter uses Python 3, so no problem. However in python2 the `input()` function takes an input **and executes it as code**. You entered `asd` - and python complains there is no `asd` variable (same for `done`). Run it using python 3, or use the `raw_input()` function which has the same effect like `input()` in python 3 - but in python 2 (i.e. no running code).

#### Edit:

Assuming you're using `python filename.py` to run your code - try `python -V`. I'll give you the python version. If I correct, most of the time you can access python3 using `python3` instead of just `python`.

Comment: wow, thanks thats exactly right! I did use python instead of python3, and that solved the issue.